# ‘gettimeofday’ cannot be used as a function

Tags: c++

What am I missing here, this is my main program, I also have a makefile and everything works the error is somewhere in here.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <observer.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::fstream in;
    int gettimeofday;
    //CPUtypeandmodel
    struct timeval now;
    gettimeofday(&now, NULL);
    cout << "Status report as of : " << ctime((time_t*)&now.tv_sec) << endl;
    // Print machine name
    in.open("/proc/sys/kernel/hostname");
    string s;
    in >> s;
    cout << "Machine name: " << s << endl;
    in.close();

    return 1;
}  //end main
```

When I try and make the file this happens

```
observer.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
observer.cpp:13:26: error: ‘gettimeofday’ cannot be used as a function
   gettimeofday(&now, NULL);
                          ^
<builtin>: recipe for target 'observer.o' failed
make: *** [observer.o] Error 1
```

Comment: This is unrelated to the actual issue (which is shadowing the function with an `int`), but a further note: `gettimeofday` is generally in `sys/time.h` for [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/gettimeofday.html) systems, which might not be included here.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You named a local `int` variable `gettimeofday`, which prevents you from calling the function `gettimeofday()` three lines later. Don't do that. Name the variable something else, or (given it seems unused) just get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `int gettimeofday;` is shadowing the function with the same name. You don't even need that variable so remove it.

You need to include `ctime` and `sys/time.h` for the functions and classes you use.

You open the file `/proc/sys/kernel/hostname` for writing, which will fail unless you run the program as `root`.

The casting to `time_t*` is not necessary since `&now.tv_sec` is already a `time_t*`.

```cpp
#include <sys/time.h>

#include <ctime>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    // CPUtypeandmodel
    timeval now;

    if(gettimeofday(&now, nullptr) == 0)  // check for success
        std::cout << "Status report as of : " << std::ctime(&now.tv_sec) << '\n';

    // Print machine name
    if(std::ifstream in("/proc/sys/kernel/hostname"); in) { // open for reading
        std::string s;
        if(in >> s) // check for success
            std::cout << "Machine name: " << s << '\n';
    } // no need to call in.close(), it'll close automatically here

    return 1; // This usually signals failure. Return 0 instead.
} // end main
```